# Conditional if with OR checking all conditions

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, shortest-path

If have if block like that

```
if(foo() || foo2() || foo3())
{
 //do some things
}
```

I need only one foo function to return true to execute that code.
But I have to call all of them.
Problem starts when first foo returns true. This way rest of foos (foo2 and foo3) are not being called.

I know that I can do it like that:

```
bool foo1 = foo1();
bool foo2 = foo2();
bool foo3 = foo3();

if(foo1 || foo2 || foo3) {}
```

But I have 18 foo functions and this is in few parts of my code.
Is there any trick to do it short and easy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `||` operator is short circuiting. You could use `|` instead:

```
if (foo1() | foo2() | foo3()) {}
```

But you should also consider making an array of function pointers and calling them in a loop.

> and this is in few parts of my code

You should refactor your code so that you can reuse it, rather than copying and pasting the same code in many places.

Comment: `|` will only work if the return values are integral. They might have been pointers.

Comment: @rob: I'm assume they return booleans because the OP say "returns true".

Comment: -1 this is a really hacky and confusing way to avoid using three variables.

Comment: @MarkByers: Was just adding that to my response.  If you're calling 18 functions in an if statement that can probably be refactored into something better, no?  I'm not religious about this stuff, but 18?  Really?

Comment: Bit operations are not confusing for me so it looks very good there.

Comment: Yes 18. Those functions are taking some data as arguments and are using those. It is hard to explain. But bit operation here works the best.

Comment: @Hooch: I don't think bitwise operations are confusing either, I would wonder for a bit why a logical AND was not being used and then come to the realization that the side affects of calling each function were needed.

Comment: "You should refactor your code so that you can reuse it, rather than copy + pasting the same code in many places." It is in many places, But is uses difrent functions. It was just one example.

Comment: I removed the -1 though since it is correct, especially with the added comment on refactoring.

Comment: @Hooch: I'm not saying I'm super awesome and have experienced everything there is to experience, but I have never once encountered the need to call 18 functions in an if statement and use a bitwise OR just to make sure that the side effects from each occur.

Answer (score 2):

> I need only one foo function to return true to execute that code. But I have to call all of them. Problem starts when first foo returns true. This way rest of foos (foo2 and foo3) are not being called.

Well if you need to call each function then you should call them.  Really, just call them and store the results.

> But I have 18 foo functions and this is in few parts of my code. Is there any trick to do it short and easy?

Why do you have 18 functions to call and test in a single `if` statement?  There must be a better way to solve the problem.  So each function has side effects and you need those to occur, great, but that sounds like a problem already.

I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, nor do I know what each function does, but I have a really hard time believing that your current setup is anywhere near optimal.

Answer (score 1):

What about summing the functions up ?
(only works well if the functions are independent and could return a positive int or a pointer;

```
int resultSum = func1() + func2() + func3();


if(resultSum>0){
 //do things
}
```